# Upgrade Arangodb on Mac OS

Tags: arangodb

What is the best procedure to use to upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.2.0 on Mac OS?
I have tried to use: 
    $ brew upgrade arangodb
That results in a message that 2.1.2 is already installed.

Do I need to remove 2.1.2 and then install 2.2.0? If so what happens to existing databases?

thanks
geoff coleman

Answer (score 2):

The brew formular is not yet updated. You can use

```
brew upgrade https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fceller/homebrew/master/Library/Formula/arangodb.rb
```

for the time being.

The database needs to be converted after upgrading. Please execute

```
/usr/local/opt/arangodb/sbin/arangod --log.file - --upgrade
```

This will upgrade your data files to 2.2.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to have done the trick. Just starting to use Arangodb and so far very impressed.